# Node.js webcrawler can't hanlde more than 50 simultaneous outgoing connections

Tags: node.js, web-crawler

I'm trying to process a large number of urls (e.g. 50000) checking if a certain string is on a page or not. I'm using node 0.10, npm `request` module and `async.eachLimit` for each url in list and my goal is to make sure this node app processes the list of urls as fast as possible.

I've set timeout to 20 seconds. The problem is once I set the eachLimit value (e.g. request concurrency) to anything higher that 50-100, after a couple of minutes most urls end up timeouted. I've verified that the these urls are actually working. `nload` doesn't show any high network usage, there's plenty of cpu and memory left on the server (nothing else is running), so why can't node be stable processing 500 urls at a time?

Even though the urls are on different IPs, I've tries setting `globalAgent.maxSockets` to 200k to no avail.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I'm not sure of the inner workings, but I've fixed the problem, kind of.

Before - I was getting timeouts and the network usage didn't top 2 mbps at most. I've tried forking the process to 16 pieces (8 core processor, but it was not cpu bound, and increasing fork number past the core number proved beneficial) and not I'm getting roughly 10 times the number of tasks per second with network usage averaging 35 mbps.